# Setting line on XY scatter without having a marker line

Tags: vba, excel

So I am trying to format a XY scatter chart in Excel using VBA and I would like to have lines connecting the markers, but for both the markers and the marker lines I would like for them to be invisible.

For some reason both the marker line and the line that connects the markers both use the same code to change their visibility property.

```
chart.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
```

I can change the colours independently using the `MarkerBackGroundColor` property, but I can't seem to figure out how to make one visible without making the other visible as well.

Any help on this would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
FullSeriesCollection(1).Border.LineStyle = xlNone
```

or

```
FullSeriesCollection(1).Border.LineStyle = xlSolid
```

to format the line only.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Unfortunately I am using Excel 2010 at the moment, which does not support the FullSeriesCollection object.  I believe my office will be upgrading to Office 365 in the near future, so I may just have to make do without until then.

Answer (score 0):

The code  seems to set point. Bellow code is sample of setting points.

```
Sub ScatterChart_setPoint()

Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim DB As Range, myCell As Range
Dim Ch As Chart
Dim i As Integer, n As Long, r As Integer, g As Integer, b As Integer
Dim vX(), vY(), vLable(), vMarker
Dim pnt As Point
Dim Shp As Shape
Dim h As Single, w As Single, l As Single, t As Single, fs As Single


    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set Ws = ActiveSheet 'Sheets("Current Account")
    Ws.Activate
    Ws.Range("a65536").Select
    vMarker = Array(xlMarkerStyleCircle, xlMarkerStyleDash, xlMarkerStyleDiamond, xlMarkerStyleDot, _
                   xlMarkerStylePlus, xlMarkerStyleSquare, xlMarkerStyleStar, _
                   xlMarkerStyleTriangle, xlMarkerStyleX)

    Set DB = Ws.Range("h3", Ws.Range("h3").End(xlDown))  '<~~ range of data
    For Each myCell In DB
        If myCell = 0 Or myCell.Offset(, 10) = "" Then
        Else
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve vX(1 To n)
            ReDim Preserve vY(1 To n)
            ReDim Preserve vLable(1 To n)
            vX(n) = myCell
            vY(n) = myCell.Offset(, 10)
            vLable(n) = myCell.Offset(, -7)
        End If
    Next myCell

    Charts.Add

    With ActiveChart
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartType = xlXYScatter
        .Legend.Position = xlLegendPositionRight
        With .ChartTitle
            .Characters.Text = Ws.Range("a1").Value
            .Characters.Font.Size = 12
        End With
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        With .SeriesCollection(1)
            .Name = "OECD"
            .XValues = vX
            .Values = vY
            .Trendlines.Add
            With .Trendlines(1)
                .DisplayRSquared = True
                .DisplayEquation = True
            End With
        End With
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = Ws.Range("r2")
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = Ws.Range("h2")

        For i = 1 To n
            Set pnt = .SeriesCollection(1).Points(i)
            With pnt
                .ApplyDataLabels
                .DataLabel.Text = vLable(i)
                .DataLabel.ShowValue = False
                .DataLabel.ShowCategoryName = True
                .MarkerStyle = vMarker(WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 8))
                With WorksheetFunction
                    r = .RandBetween(0, 240)
                    g = .RandBetween(0, 240)
                    b = .RandBetween(0, 240)
                End With
                .MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(r, g, b)
                .MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(r, g, b)
            End With
            .ApplyDataLabels
        Next i


    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see what this answer has to do with the original question. In my eyes this is just some copy/paste of a full code doing something different without any explanation.

Comment: @Peh: FullSeriesCollection(1) setting change full markers.  It  needs to setting .SeriesCollection(1).Points(i).